How to find the top level objects
Give I have JSON-LD with an array of objects or a "@graph" of objects.
How can I find the list of objects at the top level?
The array of objects may be connected (referencing each other) or they may not. If they represent multiple graphs I want the top-level object for each graph.
I'm looking for an algorithm or transformations performed on the JSON-LD API 1.1.
More specifically, can I construct a frame to extract these objects' IDs?
Clarification: As Tony McCreath points out, Top-level objects are objects that only have self-references or no references at all.

Something to consider: what if there are circular references causing no top-level object?

maybe something like this (probably need to check @type and @id keys): traversing through JSON string to inner levels using recursive function
